# More about the formal power series; for a given field $F$, what is $F[[x]]$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, field-theory, formal-power-series

If $F$ is a field, I know $F[x]$ is ED(hence PID and hence UFD). Then what happens to $F[[x]]$?

I Know every ideal of $F[[x]]$ is principal so $F[[x]]$ is at least PID. (I Know $F[[x]]$ is UFD) And $\langle X \rangle \in F[[x]]$ is  maximal ideal,  i.e., $F[[x]]$ is a local ring. [A commutative ring with a unique maximal ideal is called a local ring]

I want to know minimum constraints like ED, PID, UFD for $F[[x]]$. It seems $F[[x]]$ cannot be field, am I right?

Comment: Do you know discrete valuation rings? That's the right concept to think abuot here.

Comment: $F[[X]]$ is still an ED when $F$ is a field: [see this for example](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1145282/29335). Do you mean that you want to know what minimum constraints to put on $R$ to ensure $R[[X]]$ is ED/PID/UFD...?

Comment: $F[[x]]$ is obviously not a field since it has a nontrivial homomorphism onto $F$ with kernel $(x)$.